Npgsql connection pool max size
Context
I have an application that enables joining different data sources into a single query. The user can give as input a Postgresql connection string and query, and the application executes the Postgresql query using .NET's Npgsql.
Question
I am trying to understand what implications different values of MaximumPoolSize would have on Npgsql's connection pool behavior. If for example a connection is opened and a query executed using the following connection string:
...;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Pooling=true;Minimum Pool Size=0;Maximum Pool Size=50;

and then a consequent connection is opened to the same database but with the only different property being maximum pool size:
...;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Pooling=true;Minimum Pool Size=0;Maximum Pool Size=20;

Are there now two connection pools for the same database?
Perhaps a single connection pool since it's the same database, but the connection pool size has been made smaller? What implications does the second, different value of maximum pool size have?

Why are you asking? A database connection is something that's configured once for the entire application. Is the real question how to prevent users causing trouble with their connection strings? You shouldn't allow users to specify anything they want in the first place. You can use the NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder class to parse the connection string and set specific settings like pooling to whatever you want.

In the related question Postgres Npgsql Connection Pooling Shay Rojansky, NpgSQL's creator, answers that connections are pooled by connection string. So yes, users could cause the creation of multiple pools if you allow them to supply anything they want. You can avoid this either by using a form where they enter individual settings like server, database, host, or by parsing the connection string and removing the settings you don't want

I am asking because as I said, part of the user inputi s the connection string itself. The application then parses the input and only takes the server/database/authentication values. A customer asked to be able to also configure "MaximumPoolSize". Since this will be in consequent requests, I need to understand what affect this would have
